# Awaiting promise with nested awaited object resolves weirdly

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, puppeteer

I am using axios (npm module) to send a request to my server. This routine is part of a separate Node.js process I start, which should automatically close after its work is done.

However, I seem to be misinterpreting something about the promise. Consider the function I use to log these requests:

```js
async log(request) {
    return await axios.post('example.com', {
            screenshot: await page.screenshot({type: 'png', encoding: 'base64'}),
    });
}
```

I push all these calls to an array, so I know when to close the process:

```js
this.awaitPromises.push(this.log(request));
```

later on in the code I call:

```js
await Promise.all(this.awaitPromises);
```

As you can see there is a nested `await page.screenshot(...)` inside the parameters object of the axios call which creates a screenshot of the browser (puppeteer). This `log(request)` code however gives me an error indicating that the browser has closed unexpectedly: `Protocol error (Page.captureScreenshot): Target closed.`. This means that the `await Promise.all()` has resolved to soon because after that I close the browser.

The code **does** work when I add an extra `.then()` to the log function like so:

```js
async log(request) {
    return await axios.post('example.com', {
            screenshot: await page.screenshot({type: 'png', encoding: 'base64'}),
    }).then(() => {
        // Do nothing.
    });
}
```

The code now works as intended and the browser is only closed after the log function has (completely) been completed.

Anyone knows what the difference is here and why the last example works? It must have something to do with the inner `await page.screenshot` right?

Comment: Try adding a `.catch` (or simply a `try..catch` in an `async` function) to see if that highlights where the issue is. Also: there doesn't appear to be any point in `await`ing the post: simply return the promise. `return await axios.post...` => `return axios.post...`.

Comment: That last statement is correct yes since when there is no `try/catch` around it you can use either `return await` or just `return`. I'll check to see what the `.catch` does thx

Comment: You could also [temporarily] replace `Promise.all` with `Promise.allSettled`, which will fail softly (instead of `Promise.all` which fails hard and fast). Note you will need to modify the code to use the different response format of `Promise.allSettled`.